# Javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm currently studying javascript on my own and would like to see if anyone could help me clarify this questions I have. I'm currently learning loops and came across this code in the book:

```js
var scores = [34, 45, 66, 1023, 1030, 'Done!'];
var arrayLength = scores.length;
var roundNumber = 0;
var msg = '';
var i;

for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

  roundNumber = (i + 1);

  msg += 'Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';

  msg += scores[i] + '<br />';

}

document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = msg;
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Now that loops through the array and returns all numbers in the array. But If i were to change:

```
var msg = ''; to var msg;

msg = 'Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';
```

it only returns the last item in the array. Why does that affect it? How does making the msg variable as null change everything?

Comment: you changed the operator too from `+=` to `=`

Comment: You removed the `+` sign before the `=` sign. Therefore you're creating a new string everytime instead of appening more content to it.

Comment: @RomainBraun—strictly, a new string is created every time regardless of `=` or `+=`. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here you must understand:

- **=**
  It is an assignment operator. The operation `var x = 'something'` means that any value inside `x` will be forgotten, and replaced by the new value `'something'`.
- **+=**
  It is a binary operator. It increments the value of a variable, so `x += 'something'` will add the value `'something'` to whatever value was already inside the `x` variable. It's the same as `x = x + 'something'`

So, don't initializing a value for the variable, would just make it not having anything to add to:

```
var msg;

msg += 'Round' //This would give you 'undefinedRound'
```

Now, in your case, you removed the `+` sign, so you used a simple assign operator `=`. Every time the for loops, it will reset the variable's value.

Answer (score 2):

Making the following declaration

```
var msg;
```

DOES make `msg == undefined` initially, but the problem is that second line you changed:

```
msg = 'Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';
```

This causes msg to be equal to ONLY THAT value on the right side of the value assignment. By using `+=` rather than just `=`, you are continuously concatenating onto previous values of `msg`.

Answer (score 1):

```
msg += 'Round ' + roundNumber + ': '; //update the msg by adding previus value plus current value
msg = 'Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';  //update the msg by adding only the current value. Just like assigning new value in the msg variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at the following line:

```
msg = 'Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';
```

The line should actually read:

```
msg += 'Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';
```